# Convert Printable character to CRLF or TAB hidden char

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible using Access VBA to convert a printable character to a hidden character?  After I load a spreadsheet into an Access table I need to convert "{#}" to CRLF, convert "{^}" to TAB in some columns.

Does someone have a piece of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Not VBA, but SQL, i.e. update queries, using the `Replace()` function.

```sql
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn1 = Replace([myColumn1], "{#}", Chr(13) & Chr(10))

UPDATE myTable SET myColumn2 = Replace([myColumn2], "{^}", Chr(9))
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!  Marc